# how do I change my monitor number?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have two monitors and i have set one of the as my primary display but apps and games keep opening on the other monitor. Would this be because my primary monitor is labeled as monitor 2. If so how do i change it and or stop apps from opening on the wrong monitor? I have done some googling but nothing fixes my problem.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and desktop are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: hints only here....  xrandr   gets you the monitor names. designation a monitor primary should get you #1. that might not always help. my Opera opens on #2 .

xrandr --output eDP  --auto --output HDMI-A-0 --primary --left-of eDP

Comment: there is a gnome tweak called Put Windows that might work for you, you designate which monitor an application will go on to.

Comment: Im having trouble installing Put windows i have the zip file. is there a specific place i need to extract it to?